# Windows service that interacts with desktop screen resolution

Tags: selenium, jenkins, windows-services, registry, ui-testing

I configured Jenkins as Selenium Grid and some Jenkins Nodes as Selenium Nodes (controlled by Jenkins Selenium plugin).

The nodes are connected with the option "Let Jenkins control this Windows Slave as Windows Service".

The service is defined automatically at the node as "interact with desktop".

Jenkins slave enables Selenium remote driver service

The problem is that the resolution of UI tests is really low (1036 x 780) where we need (1600x1200).

Opening an RDP session doesn't help since the service was started by Jenkins.

**How to change the default resolution of windows service that can interact with Desktop?**

Comment: I'm looking for the solutions too but so far I can't find one!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as yours. Difference was I also have GUI automation besides Selenium tests. I ended up installing VNC service on all the nodes and wrote a script to change the desktop resolution before running any tests. However the highest resolution by doing that we got is 1280x1024, which resolved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! I am still looking for a better solution... Problem is I need both Jenkins slave and Selenium services to work on the same session, to which we can play with its resolution

Comment: I am not getting your problem. Jenkins slave and Selenium services should be able to work together.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind giving up running Jenkins Slave as Windows Service you can use this way:
[Jenkins on Windows and GUI Tests without RDC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177708/jenkins-on-windows-and-gui-tests-without-rdc)

Still - that would make you maintain an open RDP session that runs Jenkins JNLP process... So that solution is working, but not very optimal.